# Display foreign application inside PyQT window

Tags: python, pyqt

I am using below code to show windows calculator inside PyQt window.

```
import sys
import ctypes
import subprocess

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    process = subprocess.Popen(['C:/Windows/system32/calc.exe'])

    # this call is to get the process window handle
    SYNCHRONIZE = 0x00100000
    handle = ctypes.windll.kernel32.OpenProcess(
        SYNCHRONIZE, False, process.pid
    )

    w = QWidget()
    wid = w.winId()
    w.show()

    ctypes.windll.user32.SetParent(handle, int(wid))

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Don't know what I'm missing. This code is opening a Calculator but not inside the PyQt window.

Please help, Thank you.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63597475/running-a-windows-executable-calc-exe-etc-inside-a-pyqt-application/63603279#63603279

Comment: Thank you Nick, it's working now however Menus are not visible even if I maximize the PyQt window and is there a way when I close the PyQt window then foreign window detach to the desktop instead of quit.