# Display foreign window inside PyQt5 QMainWindow

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, qmainwindow, qapplication

I am using Windows 10
I am trying to display cmd to my PyQt5 Application
I tried [Running a Windows executable (calc.exe, etc) inside a PyQt Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63597475/running-a-windows-executable-calc-exe-etc-inside-a-pyqt-application/63603279#63603279) But
It just opens the application outside the PyQt5 application
Can anyone help me?
Thank you

Comment: Define "it doesn't work". Does it show any error? Does it crash? Does something else happen? What program are you trying to embed? Did you implement it with the *exact same code* (copy, paste, run)? If not, please provide a [mre].

Comment: @musicamante Yes I ran the exact same code